# shell program does not show the value of the character given as input?

Tags: shell, unix, ascii

I am inputting a single character from the user and trying to print the ascii value of the character if it's value is >=97 and <=121

This is my code and it does not work.

```
echo "Enter a character"
read n
if ["'${n}" -ge 97 and "'${n}" -le 121]
then
print "%d","'$n"
fi
```

Error:

> ascii.sh: 3: ascii.sh: ['a: not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will make it:

```
#!/bin/sh

min=97
max=121
echo "Enter a character"
read n

value=$(printf "%d" "'$n")
printf "The ASCII character of %s is %d.\n" "$n" "$value"

if [ "${value}" -le $min ] && [ "${value}" -le $max ]
then
   printf "%d not in the range.\n" "$value"
else
   printf "%d in the range.\n" "$value"
fi
```

Things that I changed:
- `printf` instead of `print`.
- `["'${n}" -ge 97 and "'${n}" -le 121]` condition needed to be splited in two blocks:

```
   if [ "${n}" -le 97 ] && [ "${n}" -le 121 ]
```

Comment: This is the error I get ascii2.sh: 3: [: Illegal number: a
Warning: unknown mime-type for "%d in the range" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Warning: unknown mime-type for "a" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no such file "%d in the range"
Error: no such file "a"

Comment: What are you trying to say?

Comment: Well, it can be done, but `bash/shell` is way better for this. I think this way is quite clear, feel free to ask if something is not. Note I updated the code a little to make it more general.

Answer (score 3):

`[` is a command in shell, aka `test` command.

You need spaces around `[` and `]`.

Moreover, in order to compare integers you need to use `<` and `>`.

---

EDIT: In order to fix, you could say:

```
read n
asc=$(printf "%d" "'$n")
[[ "$asc" > 97 ]] && [[ "$asc" < 122 ]] && echo $asc
```

If you're using `sh`, you could change the last line to:

```
[ "$asc" -gt 97 ] && [ "$asc" -le 121 ] && echo $asc
```